# Error processing http request on raspberry server

Tags: http, arduino, raspberry-pi, webserver

I have set up a raspberry webserver running on my school lan network ,other people are connecting with arduino,sometimes when they connect i get this error:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('172.17.17.66', 49153) 
Traceback (most recent call last): 
 File "/usr/lib/pythonz.7/SocketServer.py", line 290, in 
_hand1e_request_nobloc k self.process_request(request, client_address) File 
"/usr/lib/pythonz.7/SocketServer.py“, line 318, in process_request 
self.finish_request(request, client_address) File 
"/usr/lib/pythonz.7/SocketServer.py“, line 331, in finish_request 
self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self) File 
"/usr/lib/pythonz.7/SocketServer.py", line 652, in __init__ self.hand1e() 

File "/usr/lib/pythonz.7/BaseHTTPServer.py“, line 340, in handle 
self.handle_one_request() File "/usr/lib/pythonz.7/BaseHTTPServer.py", line 
310, in handle_one request self . raw_requestline = self . rfile . 
readline(65537) ‘ File "/usr/lib/pythonz.7/socket.py", line 480, in readline 
data = self._sock.recv(se1f._rbufsize) error: [Errno 104] Connection reset 
by peer
```

Can someone tell me what means? Is a problem of my server or their socket? If needed i can post my code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last line:

```
error: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer
```

Means the client dropped the connection. I'd look into the Arduino code first.